# How to detect regions with same colour on picture?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to do "people counting" using OpenCv. My cam is attached to the ceiling and looking down. Now i have problem to detect head.
  I have read http://pdfcast.org/pdf/real-time-people-couting ; I am trying to do colour segmentation, find elliptical region with same colour in it and called it "head of the men". but i don't know how to do colour segmentation.
here i show picture from paper what i want
http://smotr.im/7LDz
Help me please, thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It is not really clear what you exactly want to do. And image segmentation isn't just a black box.

Answer (score 5):

For color segmentation you need to define a threshold for each Red, Green and Blue images. If you want to find black color, just process every pixel of the image and get the R,G and B images checking the if the value is withing the thresholds defined for black color.

There are methods that use the HSV color space, so other thresholds should be used for defining the color.

Comment: thank you for answer but i don't know what is the color of my object (head). I need to detect elliptical region with the same color. 
If i will do threshold through all colors it will be wery difficult and not fast.